# zip() three 2-D arrays into tuples of 3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to zip() in tuples, 3 different 2-d arrays. I have three 2-d arrays of dimensions 128x512 and I want to zip all the 3 arrays arrays such that I get a list of 65536 tuples each tuple being a 3 valued tuple.

For Example:

Lets say I have three 2-d arrays like:

```
[[0,1,2, ....], [0,1,2, ....], ....] X 3
```

and after zipping I get,

```
[(0,0,0), (1,1,1), (2,2,2),....]
```

I know about dstack but it doesn't return a tuple of values and it returns another 3 dimensional array of (128,512,3). My code using dstack was

```
tuple_list = np.dstack((a_2d_list, b_2d_list))
tuple_list = np.dstack((tuple_list, c_2d_list))
```

Also, I have already done it using loops but I am just looking for a more efficient solution. I would appreciate any suggestion as how to do it.

Comment: Do you absolutely need them to be tuples? Or is lists okay too?

Comment: I need them to be tuples. But I think if I get a list I can convert it into tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1**

You can add a reshape to `dstack` output to get `2D` array and then map all rows to tuples -

```
list(map(tuple,np.dstack((a,b,c)).reshape(-1,3)))
```

Sample run -

```
In [163]: a
Out[163]: 
array([[31, 73, 83, 88],
       [92, 77, 84, 87]])

In [164]: b
Out[164]: 
array([[81, 15, 85, 25],
       [27, 45, 94, 36]])

In [165]: c
Out[165]: 
array([[37, 24, 34, 86],
       [60, 43, 95, 65]])

In [166]: list(map(tuple,np.dstack((a,b,c)).reshape(-1,3)))
Out[166]: 
[(31, 81, 37),
 (73, 15, 24),
 (83, 85, 34),
 (88, 25, 86),
 (92, 27, 60),
 (77, 45, 43),
 (84, 94, 95),
 (87, 36, 65)]
```

**Approach #2**

Another one with loop comprehension and `zip` for performance -

```
[(i,j,k) for i,j,k in zip(a.ravel(),b.ravel(),c.ravel())]
```

Since the question is asking about performance, here's some timings on datasets with shapes same as the ones mentioned in the question -

```
In [186]: a = np.random.randint(11,99,(128,512))

In [187]: b = np.random.randint(11,99,(128,512))

In [188]: c = np.random.randint(11,99,(128,512))

In [189]: %timeit list(map(tuple,np.dstack((a,b,c)).reshape(-1,3)))
10 loops, best of 3: 60.2 ms per loop

In [190]: %timeit [(i,j,k) for i,j,k in zip(a.ravel(),b.ravel(),c.ravel())]
100 loops, best of 3: 15.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: Both of them work really well but especially the second one. Thanks.